# Date formatting in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-views

I have below entity in a mvc model:

```
[Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

and I am using it in a view as:

```
<td title="@u.CreatedDate">
    @if (@u.DateOfBirth != null)
    {
        @u.DateOfBirth
    }
</td>
```

This is working piece of code but I want to show this date in **dd/mm/yyyy** format.

I have tried something like this:

```
1. string.Format("dd/MM/yyyy", u.DateOfBirth);

2.  [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    [DisplayFormat (DataFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

But nothing works fine for me. Please help

Comment: `[DisplayFormat (DataFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy")]` works fine if you use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)`. Alternatively use `@u.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. I have already tried this but it is also not working. It is showing an error that "No overload method for ToString() takes 1 argument"

Comment: If its nullable, then you need to use `@u.DateOfBirth.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, @u.DateOfBirth.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") - worked for me.

Comment: If you put this as answer, I can up vote and select it as correct answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 options you can use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => u.DateOfBirth) // assumes you have [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]

@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", u.DateOfBirth)

@u.DateOfBirth.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

In the first 2 cases, you do not need the `@if (@u.DateOfBirth != null)` check

Comment: this answer is the best where i find DataFormatString , becase this can avoid null problem